# Multiple if-else if statement twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

So I have an application and I want to display a planning for several users. User can select a day in a form before i display the planning.
For the week day Monday = 1 and friday = 5. I store that in my DB, user have a planning day.
So in my controller i do like this to retrieve all the users that share the same planning

```
$planningRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('OCPediBundle:Planning');
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $planningID = $user->getPlanning()->getId();
        $planning = $planningRepo->find($planningID);
        $userRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('OCUserBundle:User');
        $users = $userRepo->findByPlanning($planningID);
        var_dump($users);
        if (null === $planning) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("Le planning d'id ". $id. " n'existe pas.");
        }
        return $this->render('::planning.html.twig', array('planning' => $planning,
                                                           'users' => $users));
    }
```

in my twig view :

```
<table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Lundi</th>
                        <th>Mardi</th>
                        <th>Mercredi</th>
                        <th>Jeudi</th>
                        <th>Vendredi</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Responsable</th>
                        {% for user in users %}
                        {{dump(user.planningday)}}
                        {% if user.planningday == 1 %}
                        <td>{{user.name}} {{user.lastname}}</td>
                        {% elseif user.planningday == 2 %}
                        <td>{{user.name}} {{user.lastname}}</td>
                        {% elseif user.planningday == 3 %}
                        <td>{{user.name}} {{user.lastname}}</td>
                        {% elseif user.planningday == 4 %}
                        <td>{{user.name}} {{user.lastname}}</td>
                        {% else %}
                        <td>{{user.name}} {{user.lastname}}</td>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Description</th>
                        {% for user in users %}
                        {% if user.planningday == 1%}
                        <td>{{user.planningcontent}}</td>
                       {% elseif user.planningday == 2 %}
                        <td>{{user.planningcontent}}}</td>
                        {% elseif user.planningday == 3 %}
                        <td>{{user.planningcontent}}}</td>
                        {% elseif user.planningday == 4 %}
                        <td>{{user.planningcontent}}}</td>
                        {% else %}
                        <td>{{user.planningcontent}}}</td>

                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
```

But there's my problem, my if statement isn't working. Example i have an user who choose the day 2 so Tuesday and the name, lastname and content are display in the monday td.
Anybody can help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you print only a column inside your if.

You can divide It and print always the column

try this:

```
{% for user in users %}
      {{dump(user.planningday)}}
      <td>
      {% if user.planningday == 1 %}
          {{user.name}} {{user.lastname}}
      {% endif %}
      </td>
      <td>
      {% if user.planningday == 2 %}
          {{user.name}} {{user.lastname}}
      {% endif %}
      </td>
      <td>
      {% if user.planningday == 3 %}
          {{user.name}} {{user.lastname}}
      {% endif %}
      </td>
      <td>
      {% if user.planningday == 4 %}
          {{user.name}} {{user.lastname}}
      {% endif %}
      </td>
      <td>
      {% if user.planningday == 5 %}
          {{user.name}} {{user.lastname}}
      {% endif %}
      </td>
{% endfor %}
```

You can use the same strategy for description row

Comment: Yeah that's working. Thanks man! Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad to help you! Accept the answer to help other person with your same problem

Comment: @Simon you can shorten that code by using for simple `for`-loop inside twig. Watch [here](https://twigfiddle.com/lqd8zd)

Comment: Finally both solution doesn't work at all. I try to populate my planning with 2 user. The first user select the day 5 so friday, the second user select the day 1 so monday. In my planning, first user have his name displaying on the friday case, the second one is displaying after the friday <td>. So maybe if you have a better solution, that would help me a lot

Comment: I think It's an html problem now not a php problem, ig you can create a new question with the new problem please and I'll be glad to help you in the other question @Simon

Comment: Ok i will create an other question. Thanks for your help @AlessandroMinoccheri